# Android Spinner customization

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner

I need to use spinner as a menu. But problem is that when I click on an item it gets selected and shown at that place a behavior which I want to avoid. Secondly I need that the very first item should always be a heading no matter which of the items has been selected as in the following images:

1. **spinner in normal condition**

   [image: spinner in normal condition]
2. **when user taps the spinner**

[image: when user taps the spinner]

Now if user taps any of the items heading should not be changed but item should be selected. I have achieved it using `ListView` but I think I must use proper Android components (if it is really possible).
Thanks in advance.

I have solved the above issue using the following code, but need to use spinner.

layout file

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/header_main"
        style="@style/layout_f_w"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@color/heading_color" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/headingText"
            style="@style/layout_wrap"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="MATCH CENTER"
            android:textColor="@color/text_color_white"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/matchcenter_menu"
            style="@style/layout_wrap"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/headingText"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"
            android:src="@drawable/drp_down_menu" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

....

```
    <ListView
            android:id="@+id/mainscreen_menu"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@android:color/black"
            android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
            android:divider="@android:color/white"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp"
            android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
            android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent" />
```

Setting the views.

```
TextView headingText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.headingText);
headingText.setTypeface(Utils.getCustomFont(LiveScoreCrowdScreen.this));
headingText.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showMatchCenterMenu(v);
        }
    });
```

....

```
matcheCenterMenu = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.matchcenter_menu);
        matcheCenterMenu.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showMatchCenterMenu(v);
        }
    });
```

....

```
mainscreenMenu = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.mainscreen_menu);
```

....

```
    public void showMatchCenterMenu(View btn) {
    ScreenMenuItemsAdapter adapter = null;
    mainscreenMenu = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.mainscreen_menu);
    adapter = new ScreenMenuItemsAdapter(LiveScoreCrowdScreen.this, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.livescorecard_menuitems));
    mainscreenMenu.setAdapter(adapter);
    mainscreenMenu.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    mainscreenMenu.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View row, int position, long id) {
            CCApplication.isMenuOpened = false;
                switch (position) {

                    case 0:// Refresh
                        //refresh screen
                        break;
                    case 1:// Highlights

                        //get highlights

                        break;

                    case 2:// Preferences

                        //get preferences
                        break;
                    case 3:// current time

                        // get current time
                        break;
                }
            mainscreenMenu.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: What's your try says?

Comment: @PareshMayani: please see question again. I have posted the code.

Comment: do you want to show the Match Center always(after selection also) or what ?

Comment: @RanjitPati: Yes, I want to show Match Center and the associated arrow image before, after and at the time of selection. Please consider it as a heading.

Answer (score 0):

just a hacking solution not proper one:

Again set the adapter with the spinner when you done all works in side onItemSelectedListener().
i.e

```
       spinner.setAdapter(your_adapter);
       spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView,
                View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
             //Do works here 

            //atlast again load the same adapter
            spinner.setAdapter(your_adapter);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
            // your code here
        }

    });
```

It will load the same adapter after selecting an item and show you like before.